# How to add StompProtocolAndroid to Android Studio gradle?

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'm new to java and its build scripts. I've already got a spring boot messaging service with `stomp` and `sockjs`. I want to send and receive messages from an android app. I'd like to use https://github.com/NaikSoftware/StompProtocolAndroid for the stomp client. I have problems setting it up, though.

I followed the steps described on that side, but it's kinda outdated. The server example linked there https://github.com/NaikSoftware/stomp-protocol-example-server has one `build.gradle` file and on my android studio there are two files, so I'm kinda confused where to put them properties.

I have cleaned android studio project with default `build.gradle` files. They look like this:

first file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

second file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.chatapp"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

and I added `maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }` to the first file right under `mavenCentral()`

and `implementation 'com.github.NaikSoftware:StompProtocolAndroid:{latest version}'` to the second file in the `dependencies` scope.

It syncs properly with a warning: `Failed to resolve: com.githubAffected Modules: <a href="someLongPath/app/build.gradle">app</a>`

but when I build I get whole bunch of errors:

[image]

I tried to open them links but it returns "error 404" which means that these websites don't exist.

I also googled this error: `Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.`

I found some "fixes", but they don't work for me, probably they're also outdated.

How can I add this library to my android app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out that I have to put `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }` inside a `settings.gradle` file, not the `top-level build` one and it works now.